# clarification needed in if else statement inside a class

Tags: c++

This is an openfoam program, i had made certain changes to it. I am getting following errors when i compile

```
phaseModel/lnInclude/phaseModel.H:61:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
  if (strcmp(word name_, "phase1") == 0)
  ^
phaseModel/lnInclude/phaseModel.H:75:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
 else
 ^
phaseModel/lnInclude/phaseModel.H:136:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
 if (strcmp(phaseName, "phase1") == 0)
 ^
```

My primary need is if the phase name is phase 1 it should take up certain set of properties. For others it should take the another set of properties. I am beginner, if had made mistake do correct Me.

```
namespace Foam
{ 
  class phaseModel


  {
    // Private data

        dictionary dict_;

        //- Name of phase
        word name_;


 if (strcmp(word name_, "phase1") == 0)
 {


        //- Velocity
        volVectorField U_;

     dimensionedScalar lambda_;
     dimensionedScalar cp_;
     dimensionedScalar T_;
     dimensionedScalar h_;
     dimensionedScalar beta_;

  }
  else
  {

        //- Characteristic diameter of phase
        dimensionedScalar d_;

        //- kinematic viscosity
        dimensionedScalar nu_;

        //- density
        dimensionedScalar rho_;

        //- Velocity
        volVectorField U_;

     dimensionedScalar lambda_;
     dimensionedScalar cp_;
     dimensionedScalar T_;
     dimensionedScalar h_;
     dimensionedScalar beta_;

        //- Fluxes
        autoPtr<surfaceScalarField> phiPtr_;
  }



  public:

    // Constructors

        phaseModel
        (
            const fvMesh& mesh,
            const dictionary& transportProperties,
            const word& phaseName
        );


    // Selectors

        //- Return a reference to the selected turbulence model
        static autoPtr<phaseModel> New
        (
            const fvMesh& mesh,
            const dictionary& transportProperties,
            const word& phaseName
        );


    //- Destructor
    virtual ~phaseModel();


    // Member Functions

        const word& name() const
        {
            return name_;
        }

  if (strcmp(phaseName, "phase1") == 0)
  {


        const dimensionedScalar& T() const
        {
            return T_;
        }
    const dimensionedScalar& lambda() const 
        {
            return lambda_;
        }
        const dimensionedScalar& h() const 
        {
            return h_;
        }
        const dimensionedScalar& cp() const
        {
            return cp_;
        }
        const dimensionedScalar& beta() const
        {
            return beta_;
        }

        const volVectorField& U() const
        {
            return U_;
        }

        volVectorField& U()
        {
            return U_;
        }

  }
  else
  {
    const dimensionedScalar& d() const
        {
            return d_;
        }

        const dimensionedScalar& T() const
        {
            return T_;
        }
    const dimensionedScalar& lambda() const 
        {
            return lambda_;
        }
        const dimensionedScalar& h() const 
        {
            return h_;
        }
        const dimensionedScalar& cp() const
        {
            return cp_;
        }
        const dimensionedScalar& beta() const
        {
            return beta_;
        }
        const dimensionedScalar& nu() const
        {
            return nu_;
        }

        const dimensionedScalar& rho() const
        {
            return rho_;
        }

        const volVectorField& U() const
        {
            return U_;
        }

        volVectorField& U()
        {
            return U_;
        }

        const surfaceScalarField& phi() const
        {
            return phiPtr_();
        }

        surfaceScalarField& phi()
        {
            return phiPtr_();
        }
  }
}


// * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * //

} // End namespace Foam
```

Comment: You're trying to use an `if` statement directly within a class declaration rather than within a method/constructor/etc - you can't do that.

Comment: Additionally you forgot the `;` after the `class phaseModel` declaration!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you will (probably, as the exact problem isn't made 100% clear in the question) need to declare two classes that derive from the same baseclass, with virtual functions to define the member functions. Then use a factory function to determine what `_name` contains and create the correct class that has the functionality.

Or add the `if (strcmp(...) ... )`  to each function, but that would almost certainly be a worse solution. Your baseclass can hold all the "common" functionality and common members that doesn't change between the two variants.